# View a multi channel path report pages other than conversions in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Is there a way of seeing a full referral path report for a specific page in Analytics? I can see something similar with **Multi Channel Funnels** > **Conversion Paths** but these only work for conversions.

I'd like to select a page and look at all the traffic sources users visited before coming to this page.

For example: I want to select a page pay.html and see if users came to this page from our email have also seen a banner before that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is 'no'.

The long answer is still 'no', but, remember that you can have 25 views per property, each of which can have 20 Goals. So you  can use these other views to track goals that aren't the KPIs you want to track in your main view. Still not feasible to set up every page on your site (unless it's a small site) as a Goal, but you can certainly pick out pages that are of most interest.